# Cannot move_uploaded_file not even executing

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and am trying to upload an image via the move_uploaded_file function, please look at the section of code and please help. By the way, I am using IE8 if it is nessecary:

```
$name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$basename = @basename($name);
$msg .= " File Name: ". $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] .", ";
$msg .= " File Size: ". @filesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 //check and/or create dir for user images
 if (!is_dir("uploads\\".$id."\\images")) {
 $dir = "uploads\\".$id."\\images";
 mkdir($dir, 0777);
 if (!move_uploaded_file($basename, $dir)){$msg = "COULD NOT MOVE FILE";}
}
}
```

The $msg "COULD NOT MOVE FILE" does not execute and the file has not been moved
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect the line isn't executing at all due to the `if` statements it's in. Please confirm that.

Comment: You are correct, it wasn't executing because the dir uploads/.$id./images is already created. Thanks

Comment: why you are using pair of "\" in your code, replace with single "/" and than try.

Comment: If your reasoning for suppressing them functions `@` is that it throws errors because there undefined then why not check if there set before building your `$msg` string?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to use full paths, and what is up with the double backslash, maybe that is a windows thing.  I'd imagine the directory you're executing this in is not writable, and its not able to create the directory you're asking it to with the mkdir, and therefore not able to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//check if you have form enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form as well
$name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $basename = @basename($name);
    $msg .= " File Name: ". $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] .", ";
    $msg .= " File Size: ". @filesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
     $id = $_GET['id'];
         //check and/or create dir for user images
         if (!is_dir("uploads/".$id."/images")) {
             $dir = "uploads/".$id."/images";
             mkdir($dir, 0777);
             if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $dir."/".$basename)){$msg = "COULD NOT MOVE FILE";}
        }
    }
```